# Handling user request in Microservice Architecture powered by Messaging inter-communication (f.e. RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, microservices

I'm just starting with Microservice Architecture and investigating how to build that on top of messaging bus.

There is one concern which bothers me right now - how do I handle a simple query-like request from user or when microservice needs some data from other microservice to serve a response? (f.e. getOrderList, or getUserNameById)

I know there is a RPC pattern in RabbitMQ, but everybody is strongly recommending to avoid that (as it brings temporal coupling) and use async communication instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use async communication in order to make sure that services are temporally decoupled. Here is a [good series of articles](https://www.tigerteam.dk/2014/micro-services-its-not-only-the-size-that-matters-its-also-how-you-use-them-part-1/) that explains reasoning behind that design decision in-depth.

Also, consider reading about [CQRS/ES approach](https://adaptechsolutions.net/cqrs-es-or-is-it/) to design microservices, it was an eye-opener for me when I first discovered it.

Comment: Thanx for the great articles! Was really helpful.